# Line of sight, parallel 5ft obstacle between player and enemy

Tags: dnd-5e, battle-map, line-of-sight, fear

One of my players got frightened by a Boss after being hit by a *[wrathful smite](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wrathful-smite)*, and he's trying to put himself between a 5ft diameter and 10ft tall pillar and the Boss enemy.

E being the Boss enemy, and P being the Player. Black square is the pillar. On the left image, can the Boss still see the Player to keep the frightened status going?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Line of Sight is not the same as Cover and whether or not there is Line of Sight depends on the specifics of what the object is.

Squares on a grid are not a measure of the size of a creature, they are instead a measure of the area a creature can control:

> A creature's space is the area in feet that it effectively controls in combat, not an expression of its physical dimensions. A typical Medium creature isn't 5 feet wide, for example, but it does control a space that wide. [...]
>
> A creature's space also reflects the area it needs to fight effectively. [...]

(*PHB > Combat > Movement and Position > Creature Size > Space*)

So even though the base of the mini might take up the full 5ft square, the creature on the base doesn't. As a result, it is possible for a creature to have half cover, depending on positioning, but no Line of Sight to the creature.

To see how this interacts with Line of Sight and Cover, we need to go to the DMG.
The rules for Line of Sight are (***emphasis mine***):

> [...] pick a corner of one space and trace an imaginary line from that corner to any part of another space. If at least one such line ***doesn’t pass through or touch an object or effect that blocks vision*** — such as a stone wall, a thick curtain, or a dense cloud of fog — then there is line of sight.

(*DMG > Combat > Using Miniatures > Line of Sight*)

Cover on the other hand (for a grid of squares) states (***emphasis mine***):

> [...] choose a corner of the attacker’s space or the point of origin of an area of effect. Then trace imaginary lines from that corner to every corner of any one square the target occupies. If one or two of those lines are ***blocked by an obstacle*** [...], the target has half cover. If three or four of those lines are ***blocked but the attack can still reach the target*** [...], the target has three-quarters cover.

(*DMG > Combat > Using Miniatures > Cover*)

So for Line of Sight, the lines to the creature need to not *touch* an object, while for Cover the lines need to not be *blocked* by the object. Whether or not it "touches" the object will of course depend on the nature of the specific object.

So, if in the first example the pillar is a 5ft square block of stone, then your determination is incorrect. There is no Line of Sight to the creature *and* they have half cover.

If instead it is a 1 ft wide pillar that the PC is behind, then there is Line of Sight to the creature *and* it has half cover.

*Wraithful Smite* inflicts the frightened condition on a creature:

> [...] if the target is a creature, it must make a Wisdom saving throw or be frightened of you until the spell ends. As an action, the creature can make a Wisdom check against your spell save DC to steel its resolve and end this spell.

and the frightened condition states that the creature:

> [...] has disadvantage on ability checks and attack rolls while the source of its fear is within line of sight.

*Wraithful Smite* ends after the first of:

- 1 minute
- The enemy's concentration is broken
- The affected creature uses it's action to end the condition

So, regardless of Line of Sight or not, the frightened condition remains on the creature. But the disadvantage effect on the creature is not in effect while they can block Line of Sight.

Importantly, however, the second bullet point of the frightened condition is still in effect (regardless of Line of Sight):

> The creature can't willingly move closer to the source of it's fear.

Answer (score 7):

## The player can position themselves so as to break line of sight with the boss.

The spell description for [*Wrathful Smite*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wrathful-smite) says your player

> must make a Wisdom saving throw or be [*frightened*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Frightened) of you until the
> spell ends.
>
> As an action, the creature can make a Wisdom check against your spell
> save DC to steel its resolve and end this spell.

It sounds like your player failed their initial save. The *Frightened* condition specifies that a player

> has disadvantage on ability checks and attack rolls while the **source
> of its fear is within line of sight.**

So, if the player can break LOS on their turn, they can attack a different target without the penalties of being *Frightened*. Or, they could even attempt another save.

**But, is a pillar enough to do that?**

Your diagram shows that the square that the player is in is still withing LOS of the boss. However, let's remember that Player Characters are typically size Medium creatures. According to [Player's Handbook, Ch 9: Creature Size:](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/combat#CreatureSize)

> Each creature takes up a different amount of space. The Size
> Categories table shows *how much space a creature of a particular size
> **controls** in combat*.

According to the provided table, a Medium (your player) creature **controls** a 5' by 5' space *during* combat. Does that mean that they physically take up an entire 5' square? Of course not. For a real life example, doors in your house or apartment are typically 32 to 36 inches wide. Pretty easy to hide behind, right?

Therefore, a PC can easily hide behind a 5 foot diameter pillar to break their LOS to the boss.

Answer (score 6):

### What does line of sight have to do with “keep[ing] the frightened status going?”

Whatever is causing the frightened condition will have its own rules about when it can be ended. As far as I can recall, there are no sources of fear that have breaking line of sight as a trigger for ending them.

Perhaps you are confused about the [effects](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Conditions#content) of being frightened, the first of which is:

> A frightened creature has disadvantage on Ability Checks and Attack rolls while the source of its fear is within line of sight.

From your illustrations, the one on the left will suffer this effect and the one on the right won’t.

Comment: The spell in question is the Wrathful smite, the player wants to break line of sight to of the boss to attack another enemy without being penalized with frightened condition.

Comment: You may want to provide the rules that allow you to come to the conclusion at the very end

Comment: @Shaun it just said frightened when I got here

Answer (score 3):

**From that position, the player can break line of sight with the boss.**

However, I would like to point out that the only time line of sight is relevant to the saving throw is when the cause of the Frightened condition is the Fear spell.

> You project a phantasmal image of a creature’s worst fears. Each creature in a 30-foot cone must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw or drop whatever it is holding and become frightened for the duration.
>
> While frightened by this spell, a creature must take the Dash action and move away from you by the safest available route on each of its turns, unless there is nowhere to move. **If the creature ends its turn in a location where it doesn’t have line of sight to you, the creature can make a Wisdom saving throw. On a successful save, the spell ends for that creature.**

As opposed to something like a dragon's Frightful Presence feature:

> **Frightful Presence.** Each creature of the dragon’s choice that is within 120 feet of the dragon and aware of it must succeed on a DC 17 Wisdom saving throw or become frightened for 1 minute. **A creature can repeat the saving throw at the end of each of its turns, ending the effect on itself on a success.** If a creature’s saving throw is successful or the effect ends for it, the creature is immune to the dragon’s Frightful Presence for the next 24 hours.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: The spell in question is the Wrathful smite, the player wants to break line of sight to of the boss to attack another enemy without being penalized with frightened condition.

Comment: Line of Sight is important for the frightened condition (specifically whether or not they have disadvantage on attacks and ability checks). The LoS requirement in the Fear spell is in addition to the LoS requirements of the frightened condition.

Comment: Line of Sight is important to keep the effects of the status going. The OP seems to be asking about keeping the status itself ongoing, which is only relevant to the Fear spell.

Comment: "the only time line of sight is relevant to the saving throw" is incorrect. Several of the answers show how LOS **can** make a difference on a saving throw. You may want to edit that.

Comment: @PadMar, I don't see where any answer says that. If you're referring to how the other answers reference that the Frightened condition gives disadvantage on Ability Checks and Attack Rolls while there is LOS, I would clarify that Saving Throws are not Ability Checks and therefore not at disadvantage. Unless I'm missing something?